# Sorting PHP Randomised numbers by size

Tags: php, arrays

So I've got this:

```
$h = $user_goals;

while($h > 0) {
randomScorer();
$minute = rand(0,90);
echo "(".$minute.")<br>";

$h--;
```

Basically, what it does is, `$user_goals`, has a load of factors drawn into it and creates a number, between 0-5, and this information is used to generate the times of the goals, using the above PHP function.

It's working, it's brilliant, etc. However, the numbers are appearing in random order in which they are generated and so I was wondering:

- Is there any way to sort these numbers?

  Would I put them into an array during this iteration methodology, and then sort the array by the number's value?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This could very well be along the lines of what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6118569/1415724

Answer (score 0):

That is why PHP provides us Sort functions. Have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

```
<?php

$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
sort($fruits);

?>
```

Since your array is **NUMERIC**, you need to use the FLAG along with the sort function.

```
sort($goals, SORT_NUMERIC); 
print_r($goals);
```

Comment: So I'd have to add them into an array, say let's call it goals, and then use that sort method, then post the array, one by one, adding the function for the name of the scorer infront of this?  Right?

Comment: yeah. `sort($goals)` will suffice.

Comment: Thanks man! much appreciated, will check that this works and then give you that tick :)

Comment: Yeah and don't forget to add the NUMERIC flag.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea, using `sort()` but also uses `range` and `array_walk`to set up your array a little closer to how you already do it:

```
$goal_array = range(1, $user_goals); // Warning, assumes $user_goals is number

array_walk($goal_array, function(&$goal) {
   randomScorer();
   $goal = rand(0,90);
});

sort($goal_array, SORT_NUMERIC);
```